# Google Sheets: How to do format a formula that uses CONCATENATE as a fraction?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, formula, fractions

How to do format a formula that uses CONCATENATE as a fraction?

> "*=concatenate((Piece7!C14)," ","x"," ",(Piece7!E14))*"

Comes out as:

> "*43.5 x 23.5*"

even though I have the cell formatted as:

> "*# ?/?*"

When I just call "*=Piece7!C14*" That formats just fine as a fraction, but when it's part of the concat formula it doesn't work.

"Piece7" is the name of a sheet. C14 on Piece7 formats as a fraction on its own.

Is this a particular thing with Concat or formulas in general? Is the formula format not interpreting the strings as numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Anything with an `x` in it is not a Number.

You might try instead:

```
=Piece7!C14*Piece7!E14
```